# How to get the character (.) full stop which is 190 on the keycode chart to be included in the allowable keys?

Tags: javascript, function, keycode

The code below works, but I am not able to get 190 as a part of the keys that can be allowed. The ultimate objective is to get the user to only be able to input (0-9) and a decimal point (.).

```
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (evt.which != 8 && evt.which != 0 
      && (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57) 
      && evt.charCode != 190) {
    return false;
  }                
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Try testing whether the keycode you are getting  is 190. Here is a pice of code that you just paste in to the console. `$(document).keypress(function(e) {console.log(e.keyCode);});`

Comment: How about `<input type='number'>` instead?

Comment: Where did you get `190` from? Which keyboard chart?

Comment: Please if my answer is right, then mark it as the right one, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on this site http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html the returned char code differs from onKeyDown, onKeyPress and onKeyUp.

**EDIT:** 

Added working example of this with jquery, but it should be the same for javascripts nativ keypress event.

```js
// with jQuery
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (evt.which != 8 && evt.which != 0 
      && (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57) 
      && evt.charCode != 46 // IMPORTANT keypress charCode 46 == ".",  String.fromCharCode(46) -> "."
                            ) {
    return false;
  }                
  return true;
}

$("input").keypress(function(e) {
  if (isNumber(e)) {
    result = "Is a number";
  } else {
    result = "Is not a number";  
  }
  console.log(result);
  $("#result").html(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="result">result</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. I changed 48 to 46